# Multiple JS Libraries in Chrome-Devtools Snippets

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets

In Chrome-Devtools Snippets, I need to use multiple javascript libraries (jQuery and Lodash) in the same snippets. I've been after a solution how to load both of them into the same snippet, but could find solutions for loading one JS library per snippet only.

Is there a way to load multiple JS libraries into the same snippet?

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime I've figured it out. Having not found any similar solution, I've thought I share it.

```
(function(){
    var jquerySource = document.createElement("script");
    jquerySource.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(jquerySource);
    var lodashSource = document.createElement("script");
    lodashSource.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(lodashSource);
})();
```